# Git workflow for keeping feature branch history

Tags: git, version-control, branch, branching-and-merging, quilt

In our project, we are implementing features on top of upstream software (U-Boot). Once every year or two, development is started for a new hardware and newer version of upstream software is taken as a base. Some of previously implemented features are suitable for new project almost as is, without much modifications.

Therefore, we need a workflow that allows to track and reuse work done in scope of particular feature, without resorting to scraping it out from entire code base. It shouldn't be perfect since it's not needed often, but shouldn't be painful either.

The main problem is that sometimes feature is fixed/adjusted few weeks/months after initial implementation, sometimes this repeats several times so vanilla "feature branch workflow" won't work as is.

Both team and code base are relatively small (~5 people, ~15 LoC on top of upstream code, respectively). Usually only one person works on a particualr feature at a time.

Here are two options we were able to come up with, I'll only describe handling the problematic scenario above, since it's the only source of complications.

### **Method A**

Initial state: first/previous version of a feature is on branch X, last changed few months ago and merged to master

1. `git checkout X; git merge --no-ff master`
2. do the changes and commit
3. `git checkout master; git pull; git merge --no-ff X; git push`

Then `git log --first-parent --no-merges` shows a nice list of commits done on this branch from the very beginning.

The main problem of this approach is that it's fragile and restrictive:

- if someone does merge in step 1 with fast-forward, the above method
  for retrieving history won't work afterwards. AFAIK --no-ff can be
  forced on repo level, but everyone has to do it and not forget.
- rebase-and-then-merge in step 3 will also break history, and many people like this approach and rebasing in general. It's probably
  safer to forbid rebasing altogether, but I don't know how to enforce
  it.

### **Method B**

Every time someone goes back to work on feature X, he creates a new X_fix_this, X_change_that, etc.

Drawbacks: ugly and cluttered branch list, scripting needed to produce a list of commits out of this.

Currently we keep a set of patches in quilt. While this perfectly solves the problem above, it's extremely ugly in other regards.

Any (better) ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you think rebasing wouldn't be appropriate? I understand its destructive nature, but that shouldn't be a problem if you only have one person working on a particular feature at a time.

Comment: I don't understand what happens precisely, but if rebasing before merge is done in step 3 then the git log command does not produce list of X commits anymore, they are mixed with others.